# Trying to populate parent object's array but having trouble doing so

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I have some users/posts/comments and I want to make sure that when I post a comment on a post, that user's comment array is updated to contain the comment they just made. I tried searching around and it seemed like the best way of doing this was to use mongoose's populate, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm still a beginner with Mongoose so any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried something like this:

```
   comment.save((err) => { //save the comment
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.status(200).json(comment);
    });


User.find({username: username})
      .exec((err, user) => {
        user.comments.push(comment); // says comments is undefined, but should be []
        user.comment_count++; // also, is there a way to set comment_count equal to the length of the comments array? Should I use .pre()?
        user.save(() => {
          if (err) return next(err);  
        });
      });
```

This gives me a error like cannot push into users.comments (undefined).

Here are my Schemas:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  postedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CommentSchema' }],
  likedBy: [User]
});
```

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  parentID: { type: String, 
    required: true,
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: User,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  editedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  likedBy: [User],
});
```

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
  comments: {
    type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CommentSchema' }],
    default: [],
  },
  comment_count: { // how do I set this equal to the length of the comments array?
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  posts: {
    type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PostSchema' }],
    default: [],
  },
  post_count: { // how do I set this equal to the length of the posts array?
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});
```

I also tried population:

```
const comment = new Comment({
      parentID,
      postedBy,
      content,
    });

   comment.save((err) => { //save the comment
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.status(200).json(comment);
    });


User.find({ username: username })
    .populate('comments')
    .exec((err, user) => {
         if(err) next(err);
         console.log(user); // returns undefined for some reason
                            // also not sure what to do in this function...
       });
```

This gives me an error like "cannot set headers after they are sent to the client."

Comment: read more about promises programming. How the worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first read more about how promises and call back worked.
quick fix would be.

```
 comment.save((err) => { //save the comment
  if (err) return next(err);
  
User.find({username: username})
      .exec((err1, user) => {
       if (err1) return next(err1); 
       res.status(200).json(user);
      });
});
```

**"cannot set headers after they are sent to the client."** error occurred as you already send response.

```
 res.status(200).json(comment);
```